# Excel - using cells in equations

Tags: excel, equation

Is there any way to use cells of excel in my mathematical equations? I'd like a way to just change the numbers and the equations automaticlly update with them. I tried concatenating strings but it's not that pretty. Or maybe is there any other way to easily show equations step by step in excel?

Comment: you mean something like ```=A1+A2``` ?

Comment: Are you using Insert>Equation?

Answer (score 0):

You say that concatenation of strings is not that pretty, so I assume you have done something like:

```
in cell A1 : "Hello"
in cell A2 : "World"
in cell A3 : =A1&A2
```

And in cell A3, you see "HelloWorld", without any space (which is indeed not pretty).

You can solve this in two ways in A3:

```
=A1&" "&A2
=TEXTJOIN(A1:A2, " ")
```

(I'm not entirely sure about the syntax of the second one.)

In the first formula, you concatenate both cells A1 and A2 and you specifically mention to put a space between those two.
In the second you do the same, but you mention that the space must be used everywhere.

The difference can be seen in following example:

```
In cell A1: "Hello"
In cell A2: "Lovely"
In cell A3: "World"
```

In cell A4, you can put: `=A1&" "&A2&" "&A"` for getting "Hello Lovely World": you need to mention the space character twice.
In cell A4, you can put: `=TEXTJOIN(A1:A3, " ")` for getting the same result. As you see you only need to mention the space character once.

Is this what you are looking for?